# How do you find Leapyear in VBA?

Tags: function, vba, excel, code-snippets

What is a good implementation of a IsLeapYear function in VBA?

**Edit:** I ran the if-then and the DateSerial implementation with iterations wrapped in a timer, and the DateSerial was quicker on the average by 1-2 ms (5 runs of 300 iterations, with 1 average cell worksheet formula also working).

Comment: 1-2 ms out of how many ms? i.e. what's the *relative* efficiency gain? Just curious!

Comment: @Jean, good question, that was a few years back.  I'll try and remember when I get back to work next week to do some more testing, it'd be especially good since more answers have come in since then.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Public Function isLeapYear(Yr As Integer) As Boolean  

    ' returns FALSE if not Leap Year, TRUE if Leap Year  

    isLeapYear = (Month(DateSerial(Yr, 2, 29)) = 2)  

End Function
```

I originally got this function from Chip Pearson's great Excel site.

[Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/MainPage.aspx)

Comment: creative solution! I wonder how it performs against the others posted.

Comment: That does not take into account all of the leap year rules.

Comment: Actually, if you study what they're doing, it always works.  They check to see if the february month has 29 days, and that makes it a leapyear.  It basically pawns the leapyear rules onto Microsoft.  Chip has a lot of good solutions.

Answer (score 14):

```
public function isLeapYear (yr as integer) as boolean
    isLeapYear   = false
    if (mod(yr,400)) = 0 then isLeapYear  = true
    elseif (mod(yr,100)) = 0 then isLeapYear  = false
    elseif (mod(yr,4)) = 0 then isLeapYear  = true
end function
```

Wikipedia for more...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: this one might even be more efficient.  i like that it specifically takes the definition of leap year and works it into the answer.

Comment: the variable isLeap isn't being used

Comment: Being evenly divisible by 4 doesn't a leap year make! 2100 isn't a leap year. The division by 400 part of the test should come before the division by 4.

Answer (score 5):

If efficiency is a consideration and the expected year is random, then it might be slightly better to do the most frequent case first:

```
public function isLeapYear (yr as integer) as boolean
    if (mod(yr,4)) <> 0 then isLeapYear  = false
    elseif (mod(yr,400)) = 0 then isLeapYear  = true
    elseif (mod(yr,100)) = 0 then isLeapYear  = false
    else isLeapYear = true
end function
```

Comment: If efficiency is the goal you can get rid of isLeapYear  = false, as boolean values default to false:)

Answer (score 3):

As a variation on the Chip Pearson solution, you could also try

```
Public Function isLeapYear(Yr As Integer) As Boolean  

  ' returns FALSE if not Leap Year, TRUE if Leap Year  

  isLeapYear = (DAY(DateSerial(Yr, 3, 0)) = 29)  

End Function
```

Comment: do you mean to use the DAY function instead of the MONTH function?

Answer (score 2):

I found this funny one on [CodeToad](http://www.codetoad.com/vb_leap_year.asp) :

```
Public Function IsLeapYear(Year As Varient) As Boolean
  IsLeapYear = IsDate("29-Feb-" & Year)
End Function
```

Although I'm pretty sure that the use of IsDate in a function is probably slower than a couple of if, elseifs.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer to address the performance question.

TL/DR: the **Math** versions are about **5x faster**

---

I see two groups of answers here

1. Mathematical interpretation of the Leap Year definition
2. Utilize the Excel Date/Time functions to detect Feb 29 (these fall into two camps: those that build a date as a string, and those that don't)

I ran time tests on all posted answers, an discovered the **Math** methods are about **5x faster** than the Date/Time methods.

---

I then did some optimization of the methods and came up with (believe it or not   `Integer` is marginally faster than `Long` in this case, don't know why.)

```
Function IsLeapYear1(Y As Integer) As Boolean
    If Y Mod 4 Then Exit Function
    If Y Mod 100 Then
    ElseIf Y Mod 400 Then Exit Function
    End If
    IsLeapYear1 = True
End Function
```

For comparison, I came up (very little difference to the posted version)

```
Public Function IsLeapYear2(yr As Integer) As Boolean
    IsLeapYear2 = Month(DateSerial(yr, 2, 29)) = 2
End Function
```

The Date/Time versions that build a date as a string were discounted as they are much slower again.

The test was to get `IsLeapYear` for years 100..9999, repeated 1000 times

**Results**

- Math version: 640ms
- Date/Time version: 3360ms

---

The test code was

```
Sub Test()
    Dim n As Long, i As Integer, j As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim t1 As Single, t2 As Single
    Dim b As Boolean

    n = 1000

    Debug.Print "============================="
    t1 = Timer()
    For j = 1 To n
    For i = 100 To 9999
        b = IsYLeapYear1(i)
    Next i, j
    t2 = Timer()
    Debug.Print 1, (t2 - t1) * 1000

    t1 = Timer()
    For j = 1 To n
    For i = 100 To 9999
        b = IsLeapYear2(i)
    Next i, j
    t2 = Timer()
    Debug.Print 2, (t2 - t1) * 1000
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function ISLeapYear(Y As Integer) AS Boolean
 ' Uses a 2 or 4 digit year
'To determine whether a year is a leap year, follow these steps:
'1    If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 5.
'2    If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, go to step 4.
'3    If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. Otherwise, go to step 5.
'4    The year is a leap year (it has 366 days).
'5    The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).

If Y Mod 4 = 0 Then ' This is Step 1 either goto step 2 else step 5
    If Y Mod 100 = 0 Then ' This is Step 2 either goto step 3 else step 4
        If Y Mod 400 = 0 Then ' This is Step 3 either goto step 4 else step 5
            ISLeapYear = True ' This is Step 4 from step 3
                Exit Function
        Else: ISLeapYear = False ' This is Step 5 from step 3
                Exit Function
        End If
    Else: ISLeapYear = True ' This is Step 4 from Step 2
            Exit Function
    End If
Else: ISLeapYear = False ' This is Step 5 from Step 1
End If


End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function isLeapYear(Optional intYear As Variant) As Boolean

    If IsMissing(intYear) Then
        intYear = Year(Date)
    End If

    If intYear Mod 400 = 0 Then
        isLeapYear = True
    ElseIf intYear Mod 4 = 0 And intYear Mod 100 <> 0 Then
        isLeapYear = True
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I see many great concepts that indicate extra understanding 
and usage of date functions that are terrific to learn from...
In terms of code efficiency..
 consider the machine code needed for a function to execute

rather than  complex date functions
use only fairly fast   integer functions
BASIC was built on  GOTO 
I suspect that something like below is faster

```
  Function IsYLeapYear(Y%) As Boolean
     If Y Mod 4 <> 0 Then GoTo NoLY ' get rid of 75% of them
     If Y Mod 400 <> 0 And Y Mod 100 = 0 Then GoTo NoLY
     IsYLeapYear = True
```

NoLY:

```
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple option.

```
Leap_Day_Check = Day(DateValue("01/03/" & Required_Year) - 1)
```

If Leap_Day_Check = 28 then it is not a leap year, if it is 29 it is.

VBA knows what the date before 1st March is in a year and so will set it to be either 28 or 29 February for us.