# usage of WorksheetFunction.Year in excel vba For loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of dates in my sheet DailyData A column. I need to find out whether its leap year (in A Column) and depends upon that performing a calculation in F Column.( for leap year, I need to use 366 else 365)

Found that using below formula, I can check its leap year or not.

b = 4
a=Year to check

```
If a - (b * (a \ b)) = 0, then its leap year
```

Now, I am using below code to perform the calculation, but its giving me error `"Object doesn't support this property or method"` on line   `a = WorksheetFunction.Year("A", J)`

What will be correct method of check it ?

```
Sub DayTest()
    Dim MaxGain As Workbook
    Dim Main As Worksheet
    Dim DailyData As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim a As String, b As Integer

    Set MaxGain = Excel.Workbooks("MaxGain.xlsm")
    Set DailyData = MaxGain.Worksheets("DailyData")
    Set Main = MaxGain.Worksheets("Main")
    DailyData.Activate


    n = DailyData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    J = 1
    b = 4

    For J = 2 To n

    a = WorksheetFunction.Year("A", J)

    If a - (b * (a \ b)) = 0 Then

    DailyData.Range("F" & J).Value = Main.Range("B2").Value / 366

    Else

    DailyData.Range("F" & J).Value = Main.Range("B2").Value / 365

    End If

    Next


End Sub
```

UPDATE:
I have figured it. Changed the line

```
a = WorksheetFunction.Year("A", J)
```

to

```
a = Year(DailyData.Range("A" & J))
```

Comment: Your leap year check is incomplete.   Maybe use the one from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128104/how-do-you-find-leapyear-in-vba

Comment: Add your update as answer so it will be documented and thus help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it.Changed below line

```
a = WorksheetFunction.Year("A", J)
```

to

```
a = Year(DailyData.Range("A" & J))
```